# R ggplot Histogram group shows sum of two groups

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I tried to plot the distribution of my test and train data set in a histogram and found something curious:

Background:
I have a test set with 50 rows and a training set with 100 rows each with the same column structure.

I'd normally plot the data like that:

```
plot2 <- ggplot(data=Donald_1) + 
  geom_histogram(aes_string(x = "Alter", y = "..count..", fill = "Group"),
                 bins=20, alpha=0.7)
```

which results in the right histogram shown below. I then wondered how it could be that test has a higher count than training as the test set is only 50 rows instead of 100. And it seems as if the test bars show the sum of the test and training bars of the left plot.

Then I tried:

```
plot1 <- ggplot() +
  geom_histogram(data=Donald_1 %>% filter(Group == "Training"),
                 aes_string(x="Alter", y="..count..", fill = "Group"),
                 bins=20, alpha=0.7) +
  geom_histogram(data=Donald_1 %>% filter(Group == "Test"),  
                 aes_string(x="Alter", y="..count..", fill="Group"),
                  bins=20, alpha=0.7)
```

which results in the left plot shown below and that results makes more sense to me.

I now wonder, why the first attempt doesn't result in the same plot as the second attempt. Am I missing something obvious here?

[image: The result of the code side by side]

Comment: On your first approach the process will automatically plot the histograms in a "stacked" way. Try again using `position = "identity"` or `position = "dodge"`.

Comment: thanks for the quick response !! position = "identity" did it. !! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your dataframe, you have the column "Group" which represents both values Training and Test. 
ggplot understands that you are representing one histogram with two groups.
Your second plot represents two distinct histograms on the same grid, and transparency (alpha) makes it what it actually what it look like.

Moreover, maybe you will prefer this one :

```
plot3 <- ggplot(data=Donald_1) + 
  geom_histogram(aes_string(x = "Alter", y = "..count..", fill = "Group"),
                 bins=20, alpha=0.7, position="dodge")
```